# Execute script when process reaches 6 hours of lifetime

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, crontab

I wonder if it's possible to execute a perl script when a process with a given PID file reaches a total of 6 hours of lifetime? Can this be done through crontab or similar?

The perl script I want to execute simply restarts the process.

I have absolutely no clue how I would go about doing this, but I would imagine grabbing the `TIME` from `top`.

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141888/how-do-i-limit-the-running-time-of-a-process-using-ulimit

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the elapsed time (wall clock) that a process has been in the system.

```
ps -p PID -e etime,command
```

The format is not ideal, as the format changes basked on the duration; if you strace it, you'll probably find that it gets its information from /proc/PID/status or similar

This is a pattern I have used on occasion; another variation is with rsize if I'm concerned about monitoring a process with a tendency to run away...

That reminds me, perhaps your problem might better be solved using something like a ulimit or the timeout command (or a wrapper script which does the same).

If you have one in use, some configuration management tools (eg. CFEngine ) allow you perform actions in response to metrics such as rsize.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to grab the minutes from ps aux with something like

```
for i in $(pidof sshd); do ps aux | awk '{print $2" "$10}' | grep "^$i" | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F':' '{print $1}' ; done
```

You could then embed it inside a script and place it in cron to restart the respective services.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you wish to have the script executed automatically, so that you need something that keeps checking whether the six hours have elapsed, and executes some script in case they have.

I suggest you use the command *watch*, which executes a given command every so many seconds:

```
 watch -n 10 my_script &
```

will put *watch* in the background (the meaning of &), from where it will execute the command *my_script* every 10 seconds (the meaning of *-n 10*). The my_script file should be a bash script file, made executable by means of *chmod 755 my_script*, which checks (as per the suggestions in the other answers) whether your program has reached the 6-hours limit, and acts accordingly.

If you are worried about losing this command in the background, should the shell from which it is run be killed for any reason, just modify the command as:

```
  nohup 'watch -n 10 my_script'
```

an it will survive anything but reboots.

Comment: Not really the intended use of watch (which is a very useful program). I would suggest that a simple loop would be better, and additionally removes the headache with escaping non-trivial commands that you wish to watch. `while sleep 10; do my_script; done &`

Comment: Which method would be best? The loop or a cron job?